# Get week range for given month and year in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to display a range of dates in corresponding week for selected month. Suppose the selected values are `month=3` (April) and `year=2018`. The output should show a list of ranged dates for weeks in that particular month selected.

```
month = 3;
year = 2018;
```

Output:

> Week 1: 01/04/2018 - 01/04/2018
>
> Week 2: 02/04/2018 - 08/04/2018
>
> Week 3: 09/04/2018 - 15/04/2018
>
> Week 4: 16/04/2018 - 22/04/2018
>
> Week 5: 23/04/2018 - 29/04/2018
>
> Week 6: 30/04/2018 - 30/04/2018

I tried this function but it doesn't work correctly. Can you help me ? thanks a lot.

```js
public getWeeksInMonth(): {

  let year: number = 2018;
  let month: number = 3 //April;

  const weeks = [];
  const firstDay: Date = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const lastDay: Date = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  const daysInMonth: number = lastDay.getDate();
  let dayOfWeek: number = firstDay.getDay();
  let start: number;
  let end: number;

  for (let i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {

    if (dayOfWeek === 0 || i === 1) {
      start = i;
    }

    if (dayOfWeek === 6 || i === daysInMonth) {

      end = i;

      if ((start !== end) || (start === 30 && end === 30) || (start === 31 && end === 31)) {

        weeks.push({
          'start': start,
          'end': end
        });
      }
    }

    dayOfWeek = new Date(year, month, i).getDay();
  }

  return weeks;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! If not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that sunday gets `0` by `.getDay()` instead of monday.

> Solved this issue checking for `dayOfWeek === 1` instead of `dayOfWeek === 0` and `dayOfWeek === 0` instead of `dayOfWeek === 6`.

The second problem is your checking befor pushing a new `week`. You're checking for if `start !== end` but `start` could be equal to `end`

> Solved this issue by setting `start` to null after pushing a new week and checking for `start` instead.

(Example below is written in JS, because TS is not runable at StackOverflow)

```js
function getWeeksInMonth() {

  let year = 2018;
  let month = 3; //April;

  const weeks = [];
  const firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
  const lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  const daysInMonth = lastDay.getDate();
  let dayOfWeek = firstDay.getDay();
  let start;
  let oldstart;
  let end;

  for (let i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {

    if (dayOfWeek === 1 || i === 1) {
      start = i;
    }

    if (dayOfWeek === 0 || i === daysInMonth) {

      end = i;

      if(start){
        weeks.push({
          'start': start,
          'end': end
        });
        start = null;
      }
    }

    dayOfWeek = new Date(year, month, i + 1).getDay();
  }

  return weeks;
}

console.log(getWeeksInMonth());
```

Comment: It's returning incorrect values though. The last week starts on the 17th and ends on the 30th?

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly refactored your solution and it seems to deliver expected result.

My code follows exactly the same (*brute force*) approach as yours:

- make up an array (with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) of length equal to the number of days in a given month and fill it with the dates of each day of that month;
- cycle through that array (with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) and throw into resulting array objects (`{week,start,end}`) that correspond to weeks, generating new objects as you hit Monday and closing the end date as you hit Sunday:

```js
const getWeeksInMonth = (month, year) => 
 Array
 .from({length: (new Date(year, month+1, 0) - new Date(year, month, 0))/864E5}, 
           (_,i) => new Date(year, month, i+1))
 .reduce((res,date,idx,self) => {
    const itsMonday = date.getDay() == 1,
   itsSunday = date.getDay() == 0,
   monthStart = idx == 0,     
   monthEnd = idx == self.length-1,
   options = {dateStyle: 'short'};
    if(itsMonday || monthStart) 
           res.push({
                 week:(res[res.length-1]||{week:0}).week+1,
                 start: date.toLocaleDateString('fr',options),
                 end: (monthStart ? date.toLocaleDateString('fr',options) : '')
           });
    if(itsSunday || monthEnd) 
                 res[res.length-1].end = date.toLocaleDateString('fr',options);
    return res;
 }, []);
    
console.log(getWeeksInMonth(3,2018));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: I think its a clean solution, but you're not facing the problem of his/her provided code and you're also not explaining anything of your code, thats why your answer is only a copy paste solution. This will make it hard to understand or to learn something new. :)

Comment: Point taken. My code seemed to me obvious enough, especially considering the algorithm is identical to the one used by OP.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.
Here the complete funtion working correctly:

```
public getWeeksInMonth(): Observable<Week[]> {

    let year: number = 2018;
    let month: number = 3;

    const weeks: Week[] = [];

    const firstDay: Date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1));
    const lastDay: Date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month + 1, 0));

    const daysInMonth: number = lastDay.getDate();
    let dayOfWeek: number = firstDay.getDay();

    let start: number;
    let end: number;

    for (let i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {

        if (dayOfWeek === 0 || i === 1) {
            start = i;
        }

        if (dayOfWeek === 0 && start === 1 && i !== daysInMonth) {
            end = 1;

            weeks.push({
                'start': start,
                'end': end
            });
        }
        if (dayOfWeek === 6 || i === daysInMonth) {
            end = i;
            if ((start !== end) || (start === 30 && end === 30) || (start === 31 && end === 31)) {

                weeks.push({
                    'start': start,
                    'end': end
                });
            }
        }
        dayOfWeek = new Date(year, month, i).getDay();
    }
    return of(weeks);
}
```

Comment: i think there is still one problem. You're checking for `start !== end` before pushing the week, but `start` could be equal to `end`. Please take a look at my answer. :)